# Entity Framework: Max. number of "subqueries"?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

My data model has an entity `Person` with 3 related (1:N) entities `Jobs`, `Tasks` and `Dates`.

My query looks like

```
var persons = (from x in context.Persons
select new {
    PersonId = x.Id,
    JobNames = x.Jobs.Select(y => y.Name),
    TaskDates = x.Tasks.Select(y => y.Date),
    DateInfos = x.Dates.Select(y => y.Info)
}).ToList();
```

Everything seems to work fine, but the lists `JobNames`, `TaskDates` and `DateInfos` are not all filled.

For example, `TaskDates` and `DateInfos` have the correct values, but `JobNames` stays empty. But when I remove `TaskDates` from the query, then `JobNames` is correctly filled.

So it seems that EF can only handle a limited number of these "subqueries"? Is this correct? If so, what is the max. number of these "subqueries" for a single statement? Is there a way to work around these issue without having to make more than one call to the database?

(ps: I'm not entirely sure, but I seem to remember that this query worked in LINQ2SQL - could it be?)

**UPDATE**

I'm getting crazy about this. I tried to repro the issue from ground up using a fresh, simple project (to post the entire piece of code here, not only an oversimplified example) - and I found I wasn't able to repro it. It still happens within our existing code base (apparently there's more behind this problem, but I cannot share this closed code base, unfortunately).

After hours and hours of playing around I found the weirdest behavior:

- It works great when I *don't* `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` before calling the LINQ statement
- It also works great (independent of the above) when I *don't* use a `.Take()` to only get the first X rows
- It also works great when I add an additional `.Where()` statements to cut the the number of rows returned from SQL Server

I didn't find any comprehensible reason why I see this behavior, but I started to look at the SQL: Although EF generates the exact same SQL, the execution plan is different when I use `READ UNCOMMITTED`. It returns *more* rows on a specific index in the middle of the execution plan, which curiously ends in *less* rows returned for the entire SQL statement - which in turn results in the missing data, that is the reason for my question to begin with.

This sounds very confusing and unbelievable, I know, but this is the behavior I see. I don't know what else to do, I don't even know what to google for at this point ;-).

I can fix my problem (just don't use `READ UNCOMMITTED`), but I have no idea why it occurs and if it is a bug or something I don't know about SQL Server. **Maybe there's some "magic max number of allowed results in sub-queries" in SQL Server**? At least: As far as I can see, it's not an issue with EF itself.

Comment: Look at `var persons = (from x in context.Persons
select new {
    PersonId = x.Id,
    JobNames = x.Jobs.Select(y => y.Name),
    TaskDates = x.Tasks.Select(y => y.Date),
    DateInfos = x.Dates.Select(y => y.Info)
}).ToString()` and analyze the sql. It may drop some light to the poblem.

Comment: could you please try: JobNames = context.Jobs.Where(j=>j.Person.Id == x.Id).Select(j=>j.Name)

Comment: My guesses are 1) The query requires `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` 2) The schema of the entities are not build properly

Comment: Have you tried using `Include` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - please see the update above.

Comment: Use sql analyzer and check the query that your linq built.
it seems you have join Issue.

Comment: Pouya, thanks, but I did that already - that's how I know how the Execution Plan is. The SQL is exactly the same for the cases where it works, and where it doesn't. Only the Execution Plan is slightly different.

Comment: As mentioned in the update: I cannot reproduce the issue in a "simpler" environment than our core product :( I guess I have to give to try to understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but does calling ToList() on each subquery produce the required effect?

```
var persons = (from x in context.Persons
select new {
    PersonId = x.Id,
    JobNames = x.Jobs.Select(y => y.Name.ToList()),
    TaskDates = x.Tasks.Select(y => y.Date).ToList(),
    DateInfos = x.Dates.Select(y => y.Info).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Jon, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I tried `ToList()`. No, it didn't help, the result stayed the same. I think the source of my problem is with SQL Server, not EF (see my update).